# Setup JRebel for GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jrebel

I need to try JRebel for my web app development:

- Using GAE SDK version 1.8.0
- Run through maven `appengine:devserver`
- Under M2E plugin (Eclipse) or console, running Linux (Ubuntu) desktop

Documents I found online points into editing the GAE script, however what would be the approach for GAE run from Maven?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is starting up the GAE process with the JRebel JVM arguments or in general adding JVM arguments to the GAE process.

There are multiple ways of adding JVM arguments to the process, I would recommend adding those arguments to the appengine plugin

You can set JVM arguments for JRebel in your pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <jvmFlags>
      <jvmFlag>-agentpath:{jrebel install directory}/lib/libjrebel64.dylib</jvmFlag>
    </jvmFlags>
    <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Where `libjrebel64.dylib` works for macOS, and you'd use `libjrebel64.so` on Linux and `jrebel64.dll` on Windows.